# canConstruct a memorization dynamic programming problem

Tags: python-3.x, dynamic-programming

I am stating to solve some dynamical programming problem, I came across the problem to solve if a string can be constructed from a list of string.
I have use this following method in python 3.8.

```
def canConstruct(target,workbank,memo={}):
if (target in memo):
    return(memo[target])
if len(target)==0:
    return(True)
for i in range (len(workbank)):
    pos=target.find(workbank[i])
    if (pos != -1):
        suffix=target[pos:pos+len(workbank[i])]
        out=canConstruct(suffix,workbank,memo)
        if (out==True):
            memo[target]=True
            return(True)
memo[target]=False
return(False)

print(canConstruct('aabbc',['aa','b','c']))
```

instead of getting true I am getting the error maximum recursion depth exceeded in comparison.
I have checked my recursion limit it is 1000.
Can anyone tell me if I am doing anything wrong.
Thank you in advance.

Comment: so the expected Output is True right? Not a String object correct?

Comment: I see where the mistake is, i want to know what the output, I'm changing the Function

Comment: Yes , output should be True. Not a string object

Answer (score 0):

Ok, there are few pitfalls in your code.

1. The main issue was, the for loop, because every time it calls the function, it started a new loop, hence the index of `i` was always one, this was creating the  maximum recursion depth error.
2. The memo parameter, was been redundant to make it as a Dictionary,better in this case as a List.
3. This `suffix=target[pos:pos+len(workbank[i])]` had wrong position, it is supposed to be:

   ```
   suffix = target[len(workbank[idx]):]]
   ```

Becase you need to leave behind was is already call and move forward right?

You were doing [0:2] which is 'aa' again. Insted you should do `[2:]` which is `bbc`

### Solution

**Note**: I create as I understood the issue, if you expect a different output, please let me know in a comment below.

```
def canConstruct(target,workbank,memo=[], idx=0):

    pos = target.find(workbank[idx])
    if pos != -1:
        memo.append(True)
        idx += 1
        try:
            suffix = target[len(workbank[idx]):]
            canConstruct(suffix,workbank,memo, idx)
        except IndexError: # Here we exit the recursive call
            pass
    else: # In case it did not find string, append False 
        memo.append(False)
        
    return all(memo) # in order to be True, all item in memo must be True

print(canConstruct('aabbc',['aa','bb','c']))
```

### Output

```
# True
```

Comment: Your code break when the input is something like canConstruct('eeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeef',['e','ee','eee','eeee','eeeee','eeeeee']). but thankyou for the 3rd point I figure it out my mistake and the problem is solved . I used 'replace' for the suggested third point .

Comment: @AritrikGhosh yes I didn't really understand how the function is supposed to run given different input as I stated in my answer in the **Note:** Having said that if helped you, marked this answer as accepted so that it can be moved from the ununswered queue, Thanks

Answer (score 0):

```
def canConstruct(target, wordbank, memo=None):
if memo is None:memo={}
if target in memo:return memo[target]
if target == '':return True

for word in wordbank:
    if target.startswith(word):
        suffix = target.replace(word, '', 1)
        
        if canConstruct(suffix, wordbank, memo) == True:
            memo[target] = True
            return True

memo[target] = False
return False
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).